# Angularjs & restangular: how to use complicated routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

In my app, for one basic model i get data so:

```
var baseAccounts = Restangular.all('accounts');

baseAccounts.getList().then(function(accounts) {
  $scope.allAccounts = accounts;
});

var newAccount = {name: "Gonto's account"};
```

and then i send post request:

```
baseAccounts.post(newAccount);
```

But in my app also i have such route:

```
/accounts/batchimport
```

how can i send my newAccount object to model-url: `accounts/batchimport`?

is it possible?
and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restangular has a set of [custom methods](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#custom-methods).

which could be used to make a custom requests, like:

```
var baseAccounts = Restangular.all('accounts');

baseAccounts.getList().then(function(accounts) {
  $scope.allAccounts = accounts;
});

var newAccount = {name: "Gonto's account"};

baseAccounts.customPost(newAccount, "batchimport"); // it will call the accounts/batchimport
```

Hope it will help.